# Package was not found in the pkg-config search path

Tags: compiling, libraries, make, error-handling, makefile

I am trying to install [WaoN](http://waon.sourceforge.net/). When I run `sudo make -f Makefile.waon` it gives me the following errors:

```
gcc -Wall -march=pentium -O3 -ffast-math `pkg-config --cflags fftw3` `pkg-config --cflags sndfile`   -c -o main.o main.c
Package fftw3 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `fftw3.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'fftw3' found
Package sndfile was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `sndfile.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'sndfile' found
main.c:31:19: fatal error: fftw3.h: No such file or directory
 #include <fftw3.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

I installed `FFTW3` with `sudo apt-get install libfftw3-3` and `libsndfile` with `sudo apt-get install libsndfile1`. But this problem remains. How can I fix it?

Comment: You need to install the headers, they are in the development packages (marked -dev). See http://askubuntu.com/questions/232200/how-do-i-install-development-tools-for-12-10 and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingSoftware and http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libfftw3-dev

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The missing file `fftw3.h` is in the package `libfftw3-dev`, therefore

```
sudo apt-get install libfftw3-dev
```

And install `libsndfile1` via

```
sudo apt-get install libsndfile1-dev
```